# Error A2206 in sample assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am reading a book which teaches assembly using MASM via Visual C++ Express.

The book gives the following example program to test that masm is working

```
.386
.model flat, c
.stack 100 h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
.data
msg1fmt byte "%s%d",0Ah,0
msg1 byte "The answer is: ",0
num1 sdword ?
num2 sdword ?
.code
main proc
mov num1,5
mov eax,num1
mov num2,eax
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1, num2
ret
main endp
end
```

The problem is, it doesn't work, instead I get **error A2206:missing operator in expression**

However, I see no missing operator. Am I missing something or is there another problem?

Comment: Could you at least tell us which line the error is being raised for? Also, please delete lines of code unrelated to the problem. (E.g., I bet you could remove the "mov eax, num1" line and the problem would be unchanged.)

Comment: How are you invoking the assembler (how are you compiling) and does it give a line number for the error?

Comment: Sorry guys, question  updated to reflect line number

Comment: Don't see it yet.  Are you sure?

Comment: the problem was .stack 100 h needed to be .stack 100h, so I will now delete this question...

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using inconsistent assembler notation.  Labels are determined either by being in column 1, or using a trailing colon:

```
.386
   .model flat, c
   .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
   .data
msg1fmt byte "%s%d",0Ah,0
msg1 byte "The answer is: ",0
num1 sdword ?
num2 sdword ?
   .code
main proc
   mov num1,5
   mov eax,num1
   mov num2,eax
   INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1, num2
   ret
main endp
end
```

-- or --

```
.386
   .model flat, c
   .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
   .data
msg1fmt:   byte "%s%d",0Ah,0
msg1:      byte "The answer is: ",0
num1:      sdword ?
num2:      sdword ?
   .code
main proc
   mov num1,5
   mov eax,num1
   mov num2,eax
   INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1, num2
   ret
main endp
end
```

But mixing the notations confuses the assembler, and more importantly, humans.